# What can a master password also be called?

Tags: passwords, backdoors, disk-encryption

When having a company computer that is full disk encrypted, it is common that the boss have a master password / backdoor, so the data always can be decrypted.

I have heard some call this for "scrow" or something similar.

Does anyone know the correct name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the thing you are looking for is "escrow" as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_escrow. 
Be aware though that the security of your system is reduced to the hardness for an attacker to find the master password which might be much easier than breaking the disk encryption scheme

Answer (score 1):

A good solution would be to hold the master password encrypted by a N+P sharing scheme, where a certain amount of perhaps board members, or third parties, would need to come together to be able to reconstruct the master password. c++ cryptopp does secret sharing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing) through http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_secret_sharing.html